# Spring boot: Get current user's username

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to get the current logged in username using Spring's security but the `Principal` object returns null.

This is my REST controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/getCurrentUser")
public User getCurrentUser(Principal principal) {

    String username = principal.getName();
    User user = new User();
    if (null != username) {
        user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    }

    return user;
}
```

**NB: I am running Spring boot 1.5.13 and spring security 4.2.6**

- This is my security config class:

  ```
  @Configuration

  @EnableWebSecurity

  public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

      @Autowired
      private Environment env;

      @Autowired
      private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

      private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
          return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
      }

      private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
              "/css/**",
              "/js/**",
              "/image/**",
              "/book/**",
              "/user/**"
      };

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
      }

      @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
      }

      @Bean
      public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
          return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
      }
  }
  ```
- This is my user security service class:

  ```
  @Service

  public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSecurityService.class);

      @Autowired 
      private UserRepository userRepository;

      @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
          User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
          if(null == user) {
              LOG.warn("Username {} not found", username);
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username "+username+" not found");
          }
          return user;
      }
  }
  ```
- this is my user class:

  ```
  @Entity

  public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 902783495L;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name="Id", nullable=false, updatable = false)
      private Long id;

      private String username;
      private String password;
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;

      private String email;
      private String phone;
      private boolean enabled = true;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JsonIgnore
      private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
  }
  ```

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? How is your security conifg setup?

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Using `SecurityContextHolder`

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String username = auth.getName();
```

Using `Principal` from a Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myusername", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
    return principal.getName();
}
```

From `HttpServletRequest`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myusername", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getUsername(HttpServletRequest req) {
    return req.getUserPrincipal.getName();
}
```

Comment: A fourth way of doing this is to get it from the Authentication Token as described in https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security#controller

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `User` class implements `UserDetails`, you can get the `User` from `SecurityContextHolder` without dependency injection.

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
  return ((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication()
            .getPrincipal());
}
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it gives anonymousUser as result

Comment: @sumitmaske because nobody is logged in

Comment: I used the same method, it threw me the following error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888304/java-lang-string-is-in-module-java-base-of-loader-bootstrap-com-gaurav-studen

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer should work fine,
if using spring web MVC controllers you can also have it injected into your controllers automatically out of the box using springs default method argument resolvers (`org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`)

A controller can do:

```
@RestController
public class AcceptConnectionController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public void controllerMethod(@AuthenticationPrincipal final MyPrincipal user) {
        //...
    }

}
```

In the example above, `MyPrincipal` extends `org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken`
You can then pass this principal to your service layer.

Comment: `@AuthenticationPrincipal` and `final` should technically not be required according to https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Answer (score 1):

if you are using keycloak you can get more details using this way

```
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal();


    KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
    String username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
    String emailID = accessToken.getEmail();
    String lastname = accessToken.getFamilyName();
    String firstname = accessToken.getGivenName();
    String realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();
    AccessToken.Access realmAccess = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @cosmos asked - are you using Spring Security?

If yes, the following should work:

In your SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return authenticationManager();
}
```

And in your Controller:

```
private String getPrincipal() {
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to used to get a user principal

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserPutRequest updateRequest, @PathVariable String userId,
        Authentication authentication) {
    Optional<UserObject> userOptional = userRepository.findById(userId);
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
    UserObject currentUser = userRepository.findByEmail(userPrincipal.getEmail());
}
```