# Hide Authorization header from being displayed in Swagger3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, swagger-ui

I am using JWT Bearer token for authorization. I have added common authorization in SWAGGER UI which is working fine. But API level authorization RequestHeader is still showing in swagger UI. How can I hide it. Please refer to image 1.

[Swagger UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD78O.png)

Controller Code

```
@SecurityRequirement(name = "my-notes-api")
@Operation(description = "Update the existing note", 
            summary = "Update Note", 
            tags = "Notes")
@PutMapping(path = "/update-note", 
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public Notes updateNote(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authToken, 
                        @RequestHeader("note-id") String noteId, 
                        @RequestBody @Valid NotePOJO note) throws BusinessException {
                        
    return notesService.updateNote(jwtUtils.extractUserId(authToken.substring(7)), noteId, note);
    
}
```

I can not remove `@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authToken` from controller parameters as I am fetching the userId from this token only.

Comment: *I can not remove @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authToken from controller parameters as I am fetching the userId from this token only.* That's the wrong way. You should use Spring Security to get the user ID.

Comment: @dur can you help me in fetching the userId using spring securtiy any document or tutorial refernce

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355486/spring-boot-get-current-users-username